# Can I import doxygen tags in Enterprise Architect with reverse egineer in c++?

Tags: c++, doxygen, enterprise-architect

We're currently evaluating *Enterprise Architect* (12, release candidate).

The main reason we'd like to use it is to use the reverse engineering feature, from c++ to UML.

Our code base is documented using Doxygen tags.

Now, the parser of EA does not seem to recognize these tags. Is there a way I could enable it?

Edit:
The things I'm looking for are not to be inserted in the UML, but added to the model of the project. For instance, information defined by @param tags for methods are inserted in the "notes" of the methods and not in the "notes" of the parameters. The @author doxygen tags are not taken into consideration when generating the model, etc.

Comment: Show us an example of information present in the **source code** comment that you want to import into the UML model

Comment: IIRC EA does not care about any comments. It's just reading code and trying to create classes out of that. What would you expect to be the result of Doxygen comments in EA?

Comment: You might send in a feature request (cross your fingers, but don't hold your breath). Post it on the suggestions forum at Sparx. Tell your trainers, your friends and ask them to do the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some easy out-of-the-box customization of the parsers is *probably* not available.

I was solving similar problem of importing custom metadata (developer responsible for the class, corresponding database table or view mapping the entity, deployment package (.dll) and architecture layer, human-friendly class description, reference to specification documents etc.) contained elsewhere and making them available inside the Enterprise Architect in the form of informal notes and formal tagged values.

After some attempts to generate this metadata info as doxygen-style comments I gave up as the doxygen comment parser did not seem to be customizable and in order to make the non-ascii characters correctly imported the source code files had to contain the UTF-8 BOM preamble, which is not very 3rd party legacy tool-friendly encoding.

I have decided to go the way of generating [XMI file](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/projects_and_teams/limitationxmi.html) with all the metadata placed inside the `tags` and `documentation` XML elements.

Before I resolved correct XMI encoding of composition and aggregation relationships the project was stopped at the phase when all the classes and attributes and associations and all the metamodel attributes (as notes and tagged values) were in there in under 600 lines of C# XMI-specific code and we had the few thousands of classes in EA available for analysts to work with.

In your case you may solve the need in a similar way:

1. import the C++ code base into Enterprise Architect using the reverse engineering
2. extract the doxygen comment metadata using some tool like doxygen's [GENERATE_XML](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/output.html) feature
3. export the Enterprise Architect model in a round-trip-friendly XMI format
4. write a single-purpose tool that will take the XMI model, your comment metadata and spit out new XMI model annotated with your proprietary information
5. import the XMI model back, done.

For steps 3...5 there may be an easier way as Enterprise Architect has the [Scripting and Automation](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/automation_and_scripting/automation_interface.html) interface which allows to read/modify the model using languages like `Visual Basic` or `C#`

Comment: Okay, according to this it seems feasible, but challenging! Thanks!

Comment: Rather recently EA has added support for defining your own language grammer. That might be of help here. Furthermore I would recommend to take the suggestion of xmojmr and work directly with the API rather then via xmi export/import. That is going to be a lot faster, and a lot less error prone.

Comment: @GeertBellekens "_recently EA has added support for defining your own language grammer_" - can you link some more information?

Comment: @xmojmr see here:  [Grammar Framework - EA Help](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/extending_uml_models/grammar_editor_for_imported_co.html)